# importlib_metadata. error in executable file created with cx-Freeze

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I created an executable file using cx-Freeze on my python script and am encountering this error when running the executable at the end of Traceback

[importlib_metadata.PackageNotFoundError: importlib_metadata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIJGd.png)

i have checked to make sure that importlib_metadat has been installed and i can find its folder and files in python site-packages as well as in the executable build folder. Im new to python in general and am not finding much information online.

Comment: Instead of posting a link to a printscreen on another site, you should post the text itself here. Try putting it inside a pair of 3 backticks to format it as code.